# xcodeのエラー

Tags: xcode

画像に貼り付けたエラーの原因について教えてください。
エラーコードが検索しても出てきませんでした。
[image: エラー文章のスクリーンショット]

Answer (score 0):

文面からすると、その数値はエラーコードではなく、プロセスIDでしょう。
その数値を基に検索しても、何も出てこないだろうし、出てきたら間違った情報を得ることになるでしょう。

それよりも「System Integrity Protection」の文言の方で検索した方が良いでしょう。

ちなみに検索したらこんな記事がありました。
[iOS - Xcode Error: cannot attach to process due to System Integrity Protection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39219678/9014308)

[We Explain What System Integrity Protection on Mac is and How to Control It](https://blog.macsales.com/45473-we-explain-what-system-integrity-protection-on-mac-is-and-how-to-control-it)

[Runtime Protections](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/RuntimeProtections/RuntimeProtections.html)

[OS X 10.11 El CapitanのSystem Integrity Protection(SIP) (rootless)についてちょっと詳しく](https://rcmdnk.com/blog/2015/10/10/computer-mac/)